# stack overfllow in recursion in c

Tags: recursion, memory, stack-overflow, pixel, bmp

i have a code that read a bmp file and needs to read all the red pixels. if red pixels are combined together its a charging station. now the codes works with small pixel map but when i try to put 500**500 pixels in the middle of the recrusion the program breaks. i probably have memory problen but how can i make sure it wont crash ? 500**500 is the maximum pixels

```
pix_t* map_one_charger(unsigned char** map, int x, int y, int h, int w) {           //recrusive function that scan specific charging station

    if (x == w || y == h || x < 0 || y < 0)
    {                                       //if the specific pixel is out of bounce
        return NULL;
    }

    if (map[y][x] == 1)
    { // if its a white dot                                     //if its not a red pixel

        return NULL; // not red dot 
    }
    pix_t* temp_cor;
    pix_t* first_cor;
    pix_t* current_cor = (pix_t*)malloc(sizeof(pix_t));
    current_cor->next = NULL;
    first_cor = current_cor;
    current_cor->x_y_cordinates.x = x;
    current_cor->x_y_cordinates.y = y;
    //printf_s("cor x: %d y: %d\n", current_cor->x_y_cordinates.x, current_cor->x_y_cordinates.y);
    map[y][x] = 1; // flag, this point is not relevant anymore 1 = red 0 = white
    temp_cor = map_one_charger(map, x + 1, y, h, w);
    if (temp_cor != NULL)
    {
        current_cor = add_to_pixel_list(&current_cor, temp_cor);

    }
    temp_cor = map_one_charger(map, x - 1, y, h, w);
    if (temp_cor != NULL)
    {
        current_cor = add_to_pixel_list(&current_cor, temp_cor);

    }
    temp_cor = map_one_charger(map, x, y + 1, h, w);
    if (temp_cor != NULL)
    {
        current_cor = add_to_pixel_list(&current_cor, temp_cor);

    }
    temp_cor = map_one_charger(map, x, y - 1, h, w);
    if (temp_cor != NULL)
    {
        current_cor = add_to_pixel_list(&current_cor, temp_cor);

    }
    return first_cor;
}
```

```
pix_t* add_to_pixel_list(pix_t** current, pix_t* to_add)
{                                                               //function that creates a list with all the cordinates data
    pix_t* real_current = *current;
    while (real_current->next != NULL) {
        real_current = real_current->next;
    }
    real_current->next = to_add;
    return real_current;
}
this is an edittion to my code
```

Comment: whats the question. you cant recurse that deep you will have to do it with loops

Comment: Is this like a [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)? Wikipedia gives some more stack-efficient versions. I don't really want to work out what this code is trying to do, no offense

Comment: this funtion is supposed to find a pixel if the pixel is red it will check if the pixels near hime is red too if its red it will check the pixels near him and so on ...in the assigment they gave us a smaal picture 16*16 and my code works perfectlly with this size but when i changet it to the big map 500*500 it crashed in the middle. i need to find the cordinates in each station and then calculate(dosent matter now). so how can i make my function not crash and go over all the pixels?

Comment: Can you add the code that initialises a map with sample data and calls this function?